# PHP is not connecting in wamp ...... error 500 when I try to open phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing these types of errors. HTTP error 500 when i open phpmyadmin like--

[image]

These are my apache error logs--

[image]

Please help me, I have to complete a project within this month and this is the error I am unable to solve it

Comment: Please give permission to root folder and it's inner file chmod -R 755. its easy to give using filezilla or reinstall your php,apache,mysql.

Comment: Uninstall completely and reinstall